# Como verificar se o limite de um vetor não foi ultrapassado?

Tags: c, array, struct

Boa tarde, senhores!

Estou fazendo um trabalho de faculdade que pede para criar uma agenda. Eu fiz a maior parte do código, mas não estou conseguindo enxergar a luz para que, quando o usuário tentar cadastrar uma pessoa na agenda, mostrar se a agenda já está cheia ou não.

Segue o enunciado, posso postar o código todo aqui, mas está muito grande.

"g) Definir um bloco de instruções insere pessoa: Insere por ordem alfabética de nome desloca todos os elementos seguintes do vetor para a posição posterior.(Ao inserir deve-severificar se o limite do vetor não será ultrapassado,caso seja imprimir a mensagemAGENDACHEIA); "

Comment: Se o código está muito grande, siga as dicas [**desta página**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para reduzi-lo. Tendo feito isso, basta **[edit]** a pergunta e adicionar o código

Answer (score 0):

Se o vetor possui tamanho estático (vou supor que sim, já que há limite), você definiu o tamanho em algum momento, certo? Por exemplo, vou considerar o seguinte:

```
#define MAXTAM 100
```

Tendo essa constante você pode usá-la para fazer verificações, por exemplo, se houver um for a condição de parada pode ser `i <= MAXTAM`.

Se isso não for possível, uma outra possível solução pode ser estabelecer um valor fixo para a última posição (da mesma forma que o `\0` é usado para verificar o fim de uma string). Aí após inserir você vê se o valor da última posição continua sendo o valor fixo estabelecido ou mudou.